# How to avoid having my foreground service stopped when on Battery/Power saving mode on Android M

Tags: android, streaming, android-6.0-marshmallow, foreground-service

In my app I'm starting a foreground service with a notification to stream music but when turning the battery saving mode (Nexus) or power saving mode (Samsung) only when running on Android 6.0+, the foreground service is stopped so the music stops as well.

Is there a way to not have the foreground service stop even when on Power saving mode? Also does Battery/power save mode behave similar to Doze mode?

Comment: To be clear which saving mode I tested on, it was on a Nexus 5 it was setting the Battery Saver mode (orange status bar < 15% ). And when testing on Samsung it was on Power saving mode (Not ultra power saving mode). My network calls to the server are being blocked.

Comment: Actually it seems that the foreground service doesn't stop but the networking calls are certainly blocked.

Answer (score 1):

You could be running into a known bug: 
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=193802. There is a fix for it: https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/221708/, but it's only going into N (for nexus devices) and M MR1.

The work-around is to create a separate process to keep your app alive by starting a service in a separate process using `Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE | Context.BIND_IMPORTANT`.

Comment: Is this different than a Started Service?

Comment: And why do we need `BIND_IMPORTANT`?

Answer (score 0):

There you have it. Battery intensive operations are generally blocked in such mode.  The best you can do is to ensure that the operation is back to normal when the device returns to normal operation. First test whether this happens automatically; and if not it should be trivially simple to use the battery API to find out when to restart the service. Hope this helps...